# nextjs with layout , unable to pass parameters with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, layout

I'm using next 13.1.1, react 18.2.2, typescript 4.9.4.
I've followed the [nextjs documentation][1] for creating an application with one layout.
in other words :

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout)
{
  return (<>         
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} 
            </Layout>
          </>
  );
}
export default function Layout({ children }) 
{
  //
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />  
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

my next step is to add shared variables , variables that i can define at a global location, and share with my page props.

**so the first question is if this can be done by changing the Layout function.**

I managed to achieve this by adding variables in the MyApp function :

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout)
{
let MyNumber = 1;
let MyString = "shared";
return (<>         
          <Layout>
              <Component {...pageProps} SharedNumber = {MyNumber} SharedString = {MyString}
          </Layout>
        </>
       );
}
const Page: NextPageWithLayout = (Shared) => 
{

  // @ts-ignore
  console.log('rendering home with ',Shared.SharedString);
.
.
}
```

this works,
but i had to use ts-ignore.
without ts-ignore I get tyepscript error "Type error: Property 'SharedString' does not exist on type '{}'"

I tried explicitly typeing the shared object like so :

```
type SharedStruct = 
{
  SharedString: string;
  SharedNumber: number;
}
const Page: NextPageWithLayout = (Shared : SharedStruct) =>
```

but this failes with :
Type error: Type '(Shared: SharedStruct) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'NextPageWithLayout<{}, {}>'.
Type '(Shared: SharedStruct) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): {} | Promise<{}>; } & { getLayout?: ((page: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>) => ReactNode) | undefined; }'.
Type '(Shared: SharedStruct) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
Types of parameters 'Shared' and 'props' are incompatible.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'SharedStruct': SharedString, SharedNumber

**this is my second question, how can i explicitly type the Shared object.**

any help would be much appreciated
:-)